# Android GraphView library - Series added with GraphView.getSecondScale().addSeries(series) cannot be removed

Tags: android, android-graphview

I have three series in my graph. Series 1 and 2 use the left side scale, series 3 use the second scale by adding with

```
CurrentPlot.getSecondScale().addSeries(sensor3Series);
```

The user has the option to see all three series or only some of them.

Series 1 and 2 can be removed with

```
currentPlot.removeSeries(sensor1Series);
currentPlot.removeSeries(sensor2Series);
```

but series 3 cannot be removed.
I tried

```
currentPlot.removeAllSeries();
currentPlot.removeSeries(sensor3Series);
```

Both do not remove the series using the second scale.

Please advice how to remove

Code extract:

Initialization (simplified):

```
private void initChart(boolean isContinuous) {

        // find the temperature levels plot in the layout
        currentPlot = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        // setup and format sensor 1 data series
        sensor1Series = new LineGraphSeries<>();
        // setup and format sensor 2 data series
        sensor2Series = new LineGraphSeries<>();
        // setup and format sensor 3 data series
        sensor3Series = new LineGraphSeries<>();

        currentPlot.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumVerticalLabels(10);
        currentPlot.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(5);

        sensor1Series.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        sensor2Series.setColor(Color.RED);
        sensor3Series.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        currentPlot.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalAxisTitle("Watt");

        // SKIPPED code to add data to the 3 series with appendData()

        currentPlot.setTitle(dayToShow);

        minMaxVal = getMinMax();

        // SKIPPED set min and max bounds of both scales to manual and set the values

        // SKIPPED add setOnDataPointTapListeners to all three series with setOnDataPointTapListener()

        currentPlot.addSeries(sensor2Series);
        currentPlot.getSecondScale().addSeries(sensor3Series);
        currentPlot.addSeries(sensor1Series);
    }
```

Code to remove selected series (via CheckBox) in onClick:

```
    case R.id.cb_solar:
        CheckBox cbSolar = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb_solar);
        if (cbSolar.isChecked()) {
            currentPlot.addSeries(sensor1Series);
            showSeries1 = true;
        } else {
            currentPlot.removeSeries(sensor1Series);
            showSeries1 = false;
        }
        break;
    case R.id.cb_cons:
        CheckBox cbCons = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb_cons);
        if (cbCons.isChecked()) {
            currentPlot.addSeries(sensor2Series);
            showSeries2 = true;
        } else {
            currentPlot.removeSeries(sensor2Series);
            showSeries2 = false;
        }
        break;
    case R.id.cb_light:
        CheckBox cbLight = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb_light);
        if (cbLight.isChecked()) {
            currentPlot.getSecondScale().addSeries(sensor3Series);
            showSeries3 = true;
        } else {
            currentPlot.removeAllSeries();
                    //removeSeries(sensor3Series);
            showSeries3 = false;
        }
        break;
```

EDIT:
Workaround the problem - set the color of the series to Color.TRANSPARENT

```
case R.id.cb_light:
                CheckBox cbLight = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cb_light);
                if (cbLight.isChecked()) {
                    currentPlot.getSecondScale().addSeries(sensor3Series);
                    sensor3Series.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    showSeries3 = true;
                } else {
                    currentPlot.removeSeries(sensor3Series);
                    sensor3Series.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    showSeries3 = false;
                }
                break;
```

This makes the third series invisible, but the second scale on the right side is still visible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try:

```
graph.getSecondScale().getSeries().clear();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will give it a try.